# Reference to local int variable

Tags: c++

I have bad function that returns reference to dead string:

```
std::string & ffff()
{
    std::string j = "12346";
    return j;
}
```

And if I call `std::string ii = ffff();` I have crash. That is correct and understandable.

But now I have function that returns reference to int:

```
int & ff()
{
  int g  = 1;
  return g;
}
```

And I can't understand why I have no crash when I try assign reference of "dead" `int g` to `int i` variable.

```
int  i = ff();
```

Comment: Please define "undefined behavior".

Comment: it might work a million times, and it will for sure happen in a critical operation at the customers system

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard does not contain a notion of "crash". There is no standard-conforming, deterministic mechanism by which you can "cause a crash".

The behaviour of your program is undefined, so the language standard does not describe what will and should happen.

Comment: +1 (the standard doesn't say what happens, but defines undefined behavior in 1.3.25)

Answer (score 0):

As already has been said, you are in the land of "undefined behaviour" and you should expect that: behaviour that may not be "correct and understandable".

If you want to understand what is the compiler doing, then look at the assembler generated. There you will be able to see what is happening, and why there is a crash.

My guess (although I may be wrong) is that the string is destroyed when exiting the function, so it is clearly a "dead string" (using your own terms, not a very rigorous one). On the other hand, returning a reference of an int... the int is not "destroyed" as it is not an object. The compiler probably does a pass by value to simplify things --you return a reference to immediately copy it? the compiler should see through that. Even if you encapsulated it in an object, the memory of an int is constant so it should still be there and probably available even when destroyed.

Anyway, I see that you have been downvoted, as it is not a very interesting question by itself. You are asking why something doesn't crash while using bad programming practices, and this is not constructive --I will not downvote, as I also am a genuinely curios programmer ;)